# How to make this in laravel QueryBuilder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I want to take **the max of the progress** column that is ordered with a distinct column name.

For example;

**progress - journey_id**

- 0    -  90
- 12    -  90
- 89    -  90
- 7    -  90

the code I tried to make but I couldn't do more

```
  $impressions = DB::table('journey_content_impression')
                ->where('user_id', 11)
                ->where('journey_id',12)
                ->select('journey_item_id','progress')->distinct()->get();
```

Finally, It should give us one row with the max number.
Also, other columns of row should be available like this,

```
$impressions->first()->user_id; //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$impressions = DB::table('journey_content_impression')
                ->where('user_id',{id})
                ->where('journey_id',{j_id})
                ->groupBy('journey_item_id')
                ->get(['journey_item_id', DB::raw('MAX(progress) as progress')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you try this

```
$impressions = DB::table('journey_content_impression')
->where([['user_id', 11],['journey_id',12]])
->select('journey_item_id','progress')->distinct()->get();
```